# Want to execute same test case on multiple machine (Machines on same LAN)

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have created a website using Html and Javascript. In this website, script run the java project bat file which is stored in D:. This is fine with my machine. But when do the same process in another machine which is on same LAN, execution gets started on my machine. I also have same java project in another machine.

What I should do to the run the scripts on another machine using the website?

Comment: Please show some code / command: how you run all these things?

Comment: What's in the BAT file?

Comment: Does the web site run on a webserver?  is this webserver located on your machine?

Comment: Yep, Website use Tomcat server which is running on my machine